# Selenium - "Locator_Detection_Failed"

Tags: selenium

I'm having error when it already comes in size of the shapes in dropdown..

see the attached image
 [image: http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/510/locatordetectionfailed.png]

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to the double quotes. Try using selectByIndex method rather than by label